# Deleting ToolStripContainer from .Designer.cs file, EVERYTHING dissapears

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I accidently added a ToolStripContainer in Visual Studio 2010 to my winform project. I could not delete it! So I went into the designer file to manually remove it. Now my main form turned completely blank! I can see all my controls in the Properties window (F4). 
I did not touch anything else in the Designer file. How can I get everything back?

Comment: Oh dear. Well, what you could try is see if SharpDevelop behaves differently. Maybe it can still parse your code. Then, do a change, undo the change, and save. Now try again in Visual Studio.

Comment: SharpDevelop? Ok.. worth a try

Comment: Nope, same thing :( It's all gone

Comment: Damn. Well then, I fear all you can do is go through your forms Designer.cs file line by line and try to find what it is that makes the form designer spazz out.

Comment: Wish I did not add the toolStrip... from there this happened. This sucks. Huge bug

Comment: First, make a backup of the Designer.cs file. Then, comment everything in the InitializeComponent method out. Then, step by step, uncomment stuff. And wait for the designer to break. Your error is somewhere inside the part which you just uncommented. That would be my approach.

Comment: Also, ALWAYS have backups of your code. I recommend one of the free SCM repository providers out there, like Assembla.

Comment: I know, I should make backups more often.. Last one is a week old. But I will try and comment everyhing out and go from there...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: It's ok, I appreciate you trying :)

Comment: This is not a bug. The designer file isn't yours. It belongs to Visual Studio. Don't touch it. Now you know.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The ToolStripContainer was a bug. Because I was unable to delete it. My only option was to edit the designer file.

Comment: Again, backup and/or source control.

Comment: @JohnSaunders True, that is my fault. But the ToolStripContainer Bug remains. I'm guessing VS 2010 version is no longer updated..

Comment: No, there may be service packs and hot fixes.